# Creating flash drive from OS X broke my USB?

Tags: usb, live-usb, mac, macosx

I downloaded Ubuntu .iso file from ubuntu.com and wanted to make a bootable USB stick from my MacBook Pro, I use OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

I followed instructions from [**here**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

When I did do the `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` command, in 88 seconds it said:

> **The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.**

where I see "**Initialize...**", "**Ignore**" and "**Eject**" buttons

and the Terminal gave me following message:

```
694+1 records in
694+1 records out
728018944 bytes transferred in 88.467946 secs (8229183 bytes/sec)
```

My question is NOT how do I install Ubuntu after this, my question is how do I "recover" my USB stick? If I get it out and insert back it gives me the same error message that my disk is not readable.

When I try to use `sudo gpt recover` I get the same message about my disk not being readable, and this in Terminal:

```
gpt recover: /dev/disk2: error: device contains a MBR
```

Comment: My guess would be that clicking Initialize should re-format the disk. It will erase all data copied there from the .img file, but it will make it visible in MacOS again (and empty). You can't really physically break a USB drive by copying data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple seem to be doing everything they can to stop people from installing from usb for some odd reason.

I completely killed my old macbook pro trying to put lubuntu on it and had to install osx on it in the end. I will try again one day..

My guess is that you should format the USB to the appropriate format using the disk utility.

Comment: Pleased it helped.